# ASP.NET fails to correctly handle comma delimited cookies

Tags: .net, asp.net, http, cookies, httpcookie

According to [the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109), individual cookies in the "Cookie" HTTP header may be separated by commas as well as by semicolons. However, ASP.NET does not parse the commas case correctly - it does not count comma as a separator, but considers it just part of the value.

**For example**
If a client sends header `Cookie: a=b, c=d`, then the ASP.NET application will see just one cookie named "a" with value "b, c=d".

As a special case, the same thing happens when the client sends several Cookie headers (one for each cookie) instead of combining all cookies in one header. From HTTP perspective, this is completely valid, and in such case the effective value of the header should be concatenation of the values of all its instances separated by commas.

Does anybody know a workaround (or maybe a fix?) for this? I absolutely need to get this working, because I don't control the client.

P.S. It is ironic that, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136405/handling-a-comma-inside-a-cookie-value-using-nets-c-system-net-cookie), the .NET built-in HTTP client's (aka HttpWebRequest) behavior is just the opposite, and also causes problems. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simplest solution to getting the behavior desired (regardless of standards correctness) would be to create an HttpModule that would correctly parse this information from the HttpContext.Request.Headers and place corrected information in HttpContext.Request.Cookies.

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 4):

Both RFC 2109 and RFC 2965 are known not to describe reality.

You should have a look at [draft-ietf-httpstate-cookie](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpstate-cookie-04.html) which is a work product of the new IETF httpstate Working Group.

Answer (score 3):

The version you linked to is obsolete. This [HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) document is the latest and greatest and it specifies semi-colons. It does say that commas should be accepted for future compatibility, but this is not required:

> Note: For backward compatibility, the separator in the Cookie header
> is semi-colon (;) everywhere.  A server SHOULD also accept comma (,)
> as the separator between cookie-values for future compatibility.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much for the link.

This means, however, that the BlackBerry's browser is not made to standard. I have found that for images (NOTE: only for images!), it sends each cookie in a separate header, which causes ASP.NET (or IIS?) to concatenate them with commas (according to HTTP standard, if I'm not mistaken again), which in turn causes cookies to be parsed incorrectly.

Please confirm that my logic is correct here, and I'll send it to RIM for consideration.