# Mapping Header cookie string to CookieCollection and vice versa

Tags: c#, cookies, http-headers

Consider a web response with this header:

```
Set-Cookie: sample=testCookie; Domain=.sample.com; Expires=Tue, 25-Jan-2012 00:49:29 GMT; Path=/
```

this header would be mapped to `CookieCollection` in `.NET`. And also when we deal with a `CookieCollection` it will finally converted to such a `header string`.

I'm looking some way to purely do this conversions in two way. Surely `.NET` has it in it's internal library. I believe any class which constructs object model from text and vice versa should support two methods (here `CookieCollection`):

```
// Creating cookie collection from header text
CookieCollection.TryParse(cookieHeaderString, out myCookieCollection);
// and getting the final header which would be sent by request
String cookieHeaderString = myCookieCollection.GetCookieHeaderString();
```

How can I achieve that with `CookieCollection` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are looking for [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkh73a15.aspx). See SetCookies method.

Comment: `CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader()` omly returns `key=value` and other text like `domain` and `path` are missed.

Comment: SetCookies seems omit expired cookies

Comment: No one is looking for this.

Answer (score 22):

I know that this has already been answered, but you might like to use this code:
http://snipplr.com/view/4427/

I'm posting it here in case the link goes down at some point:

```
public static CookieCollection GetAllCookiesFromHeader(string strHeader, string strHost)
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    CookieCollection cc = new CookieCollection();
    if (strHeader != string.Empty)
    {
        al = ConvertCookieHeaderToArrayList(strHeader);
        cc = ConvertCookieArraysToCookieCollection(al, strHost);
    }
    return cc;
}


private static ArrayList ConvertCookieHeaderToArrayList(string strCookHeader)
{
    strCookHeader = strCookHeader.Replace("\r", "");
    strCookHeader = strCookHeader.Replace("\n", "");
    string[] strCookTemp = strCookHeader.Split(',');
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    int n = strCookTemp.Length;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (strCookTemp[i].IndexOf("expires=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
        {
            al.Add(strCookTemp[i] + "," + strCookTemp[i + 1]);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            al.Add(strCookTemp[i]);
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return al;
}


private static CookieCollection ConvertCookieArraysToCookieCollection(ArrayList al, string strHost)
{
    CookieCollection cc = new CookieCollection();

    int alcount = al.Count;
    string strEachCook;
    string[] strEachCookParts;
    for (int i = 0; i < alcount; i++)
    {
        strEachCook = al[i].ToString();
        strEachCookParts = strEachCook.Split(';');
        int intEachCookPartsCount = strEachCookParts.Length;
        string strCNameAndCValue = string.Empty;
        string strPNameAndPValue = string.Empty;
        string strDNameAndDValue = string.Empty;
        string[] NameValuePairTemp;
        Cookie cookTemp = new Cookie();

        for (int j = 0; j < intEachCookPartsCount; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                strCNameAndCValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                if (strCNameAndCValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    int firstEqual = strCNameAndCValue.IndexOf("=");
                    string firstName = strCNameAndCValue.Substring(0, firstEqual);
                    string allValue = strCNameAndCValue.Substring(firstEqual + 1, strCNameAndCValue.Length - (firstEqual + 1));
                    cookTemp.Name = firstName;
                    cookTemp.Value = allValue;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (strEachCookParts[j].IndexOf("path", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                strPNameAndPValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                if (strPNameAndPValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    NameValuePairTemp = strPNameAndPValue.Split('=');
                    if (NameValuePairTemp[1] != string.Empty)
                    {
                        cookTemp.Path = NameValuePairTemp[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cookTemp.Path = "/";
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (strEachCookParts[j].IndexOf("domain", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                strDNameAndDValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                if (strDNameAndDValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    NameValuePairTemp = strDNameAndDValue.Split('=');

                    if (NameValuePairTemp[1] != string.Empty)
                    {
                        cookTemp.Domain = NameValuePairTemp[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cookTemp.Domain = strHost;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (cookTemp.Path == string.Empty)
        {
            cookTemp.Path = "/";
        }
        if (cookTemp.Domain == string.Empty)
        {
            cookTemp.Domain = strHost;
        }
        cc.Add(cookTemp);
    }
    return cc;
}
```

This code will read in cookies that are comma separated and correctly parse all parts of each cookie including name, expiration, path, value, and domain.

Comment: This solution worked great for me. CookieContainer.SetCookies method threw a parsing error for me complaining about "path=/wp-content/plugins" on one wordpress site. "Manually" parsing cookies and adding the CookieCollection to the CookieContainer was the only way out. Your code saved me a lot of time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would this fail if the cookie value contained a comma?

Comment: This was a big help. Thanks!

Comment: Why assume comma separated, isn't semicolon more common?

Comment: @Jim W, I suppose you could modify the code to allow for any separator, but semicolons are used to delimit the parts of a cookie in a Set-Cookie header (value, expiration, domain, etc).

Comment: I appreciate and am using your code, and I say this to be helpful to whoever needs it; it seems like comma delimiting lost out to semicolon, see the discussion of the 'standards' there (browsers seem to send semicolon) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394561/asp-net-fails-to-correctly-handle-comma-delimited-cookies

Comment: I would also propose returning `List<Cookie>` since this solution will does not support [handling multiple cookies with the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24214538/901156) and will end up merging them by their name.

Comment: Now, this is what we are looking for.

Comment: There is bug in this logic when you parse something like this: preutid=1; Expires=Tue, 12 Oct 2021 10:55:32 GMT; Domain=.['utraff.com', 'itraff.net']; SameSite=None; Secure; Path=/

Comment: Feel free to make a suggestion for an edit to fix the bug. It's been several years since I've been able to look at the code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my extension class I use to do this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

namespace YourProjectName.Extensions
{
     public static class HttpCookieExtension
    {
         static Regex rxCookieParts = new Regex(@"(?<name>.*?)\=(?<value>.*?)\;|(?<name>\bsecure\b|\bhttponly\b)", RegexOptions.Compiled |RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
         static Regex rxRemoveCommaFromDate = new Regex(@"\bexpires\b\=.*?(\;|$)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
         public static bool GetHttpCookies(this NameValueCollection collection, int index , out List<HttpCookie> cookies)
         {
             cookies = new List<HttpCookie>();

             if (collection.AllKeys[index].ToLower() != "set-cookie") return false;
             try
             {

                 string rawcookieString = rxRemoveCommaFromDate.Replace(collection[index],  new MatchEvaluator(RemoveComma));

                 string[] rawCookies = rawcookieString.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                 foreach (var rawCookie in rawCookies)
                 {
                    cookies.Add(rawCookie.ToHttpCookie());
                 }
                 return true;
             }
             catch (Exception)
             {

                 return false;
             }
         }


         public static bool GetHttpCookiesFromHeader(this string cookieHeader, out CookieCollection cookies)
         {
             cookies = new CookieCollection();


             try
             {

                 string rawcookieString = rxRemoveCommaFromDate.Replace(cookieHeader, new MatchEvaluator(RemoveComma));

                 string[] rawCookies = rawcookieString.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                 if (rawCookies.Length == 0)
                 {
                     cookies.Add(rawcookieString.ToCookie());
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    foreach (var rawCookie in rawCookies)
                    {
                        cookies.Add(rawCookie.ToCookie());
                    }
                 }

                 return true;
             }
             catch (Exception)
             {
                 throw;
             }
         }




         public static Cookie ToCookie(this string rawCookie)
         {

             if (!rawCookie.EndsWith(";")) rawCookie += ";";

             MatchCollection maches = rxCookieParts.Matches(rawCookie);

             Cookie cookie = new Cookie(maches[0].Groups["name"].Value.Trim(), maches[0].Groups["value"].Value.Trim());

             for (int i = 1; i < maches.Count; i++)
             {
                 switch (maches[i].Groups["name"].Value.ToLower().Trim())
                 {
                     case "domain":
                         cookie.Domain = maches[i].Groups["value"].Value;
                         break;
                     case "expires":

                         DateTime dt;

                         if (DateTime.TryParse(maches[i].Groups["value"].Value, out dt))
                         {
                             cookie.Expires = dt;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                         }
                         break;
                     case "path":
                         cookie.Path = maches[i].Groups["value"].Value;
                         break;
                     case "secure":
                         cookie.Secure = true;
                         break;
                     case "httponly":
                         cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                         break;
                 }
             }
             return cookie;


         }

         public static HttpCookie ToHttpCookie(this string rawCookie)
         {
             MatchCollection maches = rxCookieParts.Matches(rawCookie);

             HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(maches[0].Groups["name"].Value, maches[0].Groups["value"].Value);

             for (int i = 1; i < maches.Count; i++)
             {
                 switch (maches[i].Groups["name"].Value.ToLower().Trim())
                 {
                     case "domain":
                         cookie.Domain = maches[i].Groups["value"].Value;
                         break;
                     case "expires":

                         DateTime dt;

                         if (DateTime.TryParse(maches[i].Groups["value"].Value, out dt))
                         {
                             cookie.Expires = dt;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                         }
                         break;
                     case "path":
                         cookie.Path = maches[i].Groups["value"].Value;
                         break;
                     case "secure":
                         cookie.Secure = true;
                         break;
                     case "httponly":
                         cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                         break;
                 }
             }
             return cookie;
         }

         private static KeyValuePair<string, string> SplitToPair(this string input)
         {
            string[]  parts= input.Split(new char[] {'='},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(parts[0],parts[1]);
         }

         private static string RemoveComma(Match match)
         {
             return match.Value.Replace(',', ' ');
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is HttpCookie ?