# Safe way to encode a cookie value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

When storing a value in a cookie using C#, what is the best way to encode (or escape) the value so that it can be retrieved and decoded/unescaped reliably?

I'm not talking about encryption.

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136405/handling-a-comma-inside-a-cookie-value-using-nets-c-system-net-cookie)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, the safest thing to do is use UrlEncoding (use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode).

Comment: A good explanation of why this is true can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/allowed-characters-in-cookies)