# Exception calling Add. Part of cookie is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, httpcookie

I am using the `Add` method of `System.Net.CookieContainer`.  It has worked well over the years but suddenly I am getting:

> Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "The
>   'Value'='321,386,%2F%3Fa%3D1,http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxx.com%2Fpremium%2Fmoney'
>   part of the cookie is invalid."

I was adding a cookie returned from a web page.  The raw header from the web page is:

```
...
_chartbeat_uuniq=1;
_chartbeat5=321,386,%2F%3Fa%3D1,http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com%2Fpremium%2Fmoney;
gs_p_GSN-375009-Z=0;
...
```

What is wrong with the cookie value?  Is it the comma?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should encode the cookie value. The [.NET method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-8.0) is `UrlEncode` in the `System.Web.HttpUtility` API. In .NET Framework, this `UrlEncode` method [was provided by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8.1) the `System.Web.HttpServerUtility` API. See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700628/safe-way-to-encode-a-cookie-value-in-c-sharp).

Comment: I was thinking of that, but the cookie value already looks Url encoded.

Comment: maybe you should UrlDecode what you have and then encode it again

Comment: I turned on Fiddler2 and find that IE and Chrome are quite happy with the comma.  It is only the CookieContainer class that balks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-net-cookie-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-string-system-string))

> The value parameter for a Cookie must not be a null reference (Nothing
> in Visual Basic). The semicolon (";") and comma (",") characters are
> reserved and cannot be passed in the value parameter unless the string
> passed in the value parameter is enclosed in double quotes.

Following code will throw exception.

```
System.Net.Cookie cookie = new System.Net.Cookie("contoso", "123,456", "", "contoso.com");
new CookieContainer().Add(cookie);
```

However, if you add double quotes \" to the beginning and end of the value, the code will pass.

```
System.Net.Cookie cookie = new System.Net.Cookie("contoso", "\"123,456\"", "", "contoso.com");
new CookieContainer().Add(cookie);
```