# Send commas in value for HttpWebRequest cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to send a cookie with a request to an Asp.net page. From what I understand it expects the cookies value to NOT be encoded. If I encode the value it doesn't register it.

`CookieContainer` won't let me add the non encoded value to it though. I can't seem to find a work around...

My code is essentially

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http:\\whatever");
string cookieName = "whatevername";
string cookieValue = "version=1&Type=a,b,c,d,e,f";
Cookie cook = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, "/", "mypage");
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
cookies.Add(cook);
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

This throws a CookieException saying "`The 'Value'='version=1&Type=a,b,c,d,e,f' part of the cookie is invalid.`"

Comment: Why not add 2 separate values `version` and `Type`?

Comment: The problem isn't with the `&`, it's with the commas.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `UrlEncoding` value.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http:\\whatever");
string cookieName = "whatevername";
string cookieValue = "version=1&Type=a,b,c,d,e,f";
Cookie cook = new Cookie(cookieName, Server.UrlEncode(cookieValue), "/", "mypage");
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
cookies.Add(cook);
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

Comment: I have tried `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` which doesn't work as apparently in asp.net you don't unencode them (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136405/handling-a-comma-inside-a-cookie-value-using-nets-c-system-net-cookie).